# Pseudocode for removing a node of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Suppose that p is a pointer to a node in a linked list, and *p is not the tail node. What are the steps to removing the node after *p? Use one short English sentence for each step.

My thoughts were:
1) Create a temporary variable of type class node and assigns p->next to the temporary variable – call this variable temp.

2) Assign temp’s next pointer to p’s next pointer.

3) Set the next pointer of the node after *p to NULL.

This has made it so that the node after *p does not exist in the linked list, but does it still take up memory? Or since in step 3 I set the pointer to NULL, that node I removed now has no more memory? Would I need to use free() or delete function?

Comment: Draw a picture, it will surely help.

Comment: yes, it takes up memory, you haven't changed anything except update a few pointer values. the "deleted" node is still there, and has your temp variable pointing at it.

Comment: @jxh if the linked list has 3 nodes, lets say it has data 1, 2, and 3, and the *p is the head pointer, the linked list should look like 1, 3 when the node after *p is removed (the node with 2 as the data).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to describe deleteing a node in a single-linked list.

What is correct in your description is that you need a temporary variable that will point to the deleted node.

Thus the steps can be the following.

```
1) define a temporary pointer to Node and assign the value in p->next to the temporary pointer.
2) assign the value in data member next of the temporary pointer to the data member next of p.
3) delete node pointed to by the temporary pointer.
```

In C++ the code will look the following way

```
1) Node *temp = p->next;
2) p->next = temp->next;
3) delete temp;
```

Comment: Thanks! Would the free() function also work instead of delete?

Comment: @user3874530  It depends on how a node was allocated. In C++ there are used operators new and delete. In C there are used functions malloc() and free()